# How to select text between commas in Richtextbox

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, click, richtextbox, messagebox

In the RichtextBox with some words with commas between them.I have to find the word which i clicked in the whole.And the word between commas must be shown in messagebox.

```
Ex:-  Sachin Tendulkar (40),Virendra shewag,Mahendra singh Dhoni(12)
```

The whole sentence is `lable text`.If i click on `Sachin`.Then the message must be

```
Sachin Tendulkar(40)
```

And if i click on `sehwag` the `messagebox` must show

```
Virendra shewag.
```

The word between commas must be shown.
Any one please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a custom algorithm to account for that. You haven't written anything and I cannot write it for you, thus I will include just the basic parts and most important issues to be taken into consideration:

```
private void richTextBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectionFirst = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
}
```

You have to rely on the `Click Event` of the given `RichTextBox` (`richTextBox1` from now on) to get the start index of the `Selection` (`selectionFirst`).

You have to create a function to analyse the whole string from the given index forwards and backwards until finding a comma or the first/last character. The outputs from this function will be the first (`indexFirst`) and the last (`indexLast`) indices.

With this two indices you can define the selection range you want:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = indexFirst;
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = indexLast - indexFirst;
```

And there you have it.

--------- UPDATE WHOLE CODE

```
private int[] findFirstLastChar(int curIndex)
{
    int[] outIndices = new int[3];
    string curText = richTextBox1.Text;

    if (curText.Trim().Length < 1)
    {
        return outIndices;
    }

    int maxVal = 0;
    int iniVal = curIndex;
    bool completed = false;
    int count0 = 0;
    do
    {
        count0 = count0 + 1;

        if (count0 == 1)
        {
            //Backwards
        }
        else
        {
            //Forwards
            maxVal = curText.Length - 1;
        }

        completed = false;
        int count1 = curIndex;
        if (count1 == maxVal)
        {
            outIndices[count0] = count1;
        }
        else
        {
            do
            {
                if (count0 == 1)
                {
                    count1 = count1 - 1;
                    if (count1 <= maxVal)
                    {
                        completed = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    count1 = count1 + 1;
                    if (count1 >= maxVal)
                    {
                        completed = true;
                    }
                }

                if (count1 >= 0 && count1 <= curText.Length)
                {
                    if (curText.Substring(count1, 1) == "," || completed)
                    {
                        outIndices[count0] = count1;
                        if ((count0 == 1 && !completed) || (count0 == 2 && completed))
                        {
                            outIndices[count0] = outIndices[count0] + 1;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } while (!completed);
        }
    } while (count0 < 2);


    return outIndices;
}
```

And in the click event:

```
private void richTextBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] indices = findFirstLastChar(richTextBox1.SelectionStart);

    if (indices[1] <= indices[2])
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = indices[1];
        richTextBox1.SelectionLength = indices[2] - indices[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know. You have to build a function to take of it. This is what I meant with " create a function to analyse the whole string from the given index...". This is pretty easy. I will update my code to include a small code showing you how to proceed but not the whole function... Give 5 mins.

Comment: Thank for you valuble reply.Here i have done it but, I cannot find text between commas.My output was if i click on sachin i am getting sachin.But, I need the whole  word between commas. i will be waiting.please show code brother

Comment: http://blog.csharphelper.com/2012/01/02/find-the-word-under-the-mouse-in-a-richtextbox-control-in-c.aspx

Comment: There you have a sample code. See? It is pretty easy. You have to write the forwards part and call this function twice or put it inside a loop and let it do one and then the other.

Comment: I used the above link earlier.thanks bro.I will check your code and get back to you.

Comment: The link above complicates things unnecessarily (to get the start index, at least). Just rely on the Click event of the RichtextBox to get the start index and then do the other steps I suggested.

Comment: Bro.Unable to find index last..please post the whole code...please has to submit today.I will be waiting

Comment: The whole point is you writing the code by your own; but well... today I did already break my rule once... Wait some minutes I am doing something else.

Comment: I am new to winforms.This is my first task in my new company.Earlier I  worked on web applications.

Comment: Brother I will be waiting.

Comment: But then... you should learn rather than expecting someone doing it for you. Anyway... There you have it. At least, try to learn from it and maximise as much as possible the break of the rule "don't deliver full codes to someone who hasn't even tried". I hope that you will try harder next time before requesting the whole code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.And the code is good I understood.but i tried brother.And one more thing i have to show the text in message box.

Comment: I guess that you can do this by your own. Otherwise, perhaps you should start considering working on other things :) It is extremelly simple, google it and ask here serious problems which cannot be found so easily. Or you can post a new question, I have done more than enough.

Comment: Let's better close this close, don't you think?

Comment: k.Brother thank you very much i have already done it.Just telling about the task.Thanks for considering me.

Comment: Considering you? I consider everyone who aims something fair. To be honest, not too sure that what you aim is fair (mainly for you) but well... what is done is done. If you learn from this, from my code and start to use this site as is intended to be used (bear in mind that if everyone would behave like you do, nobody would be here to answer your question), I would be happy.

Comment: sure I will work hard.And one day I will try to answer someones questions.

Comment: Excellent! For the time being, just learn from the code I gave you and set this answer as the right one ;)

Comment: Thanks for the award. I guess that my last comment was half-unnecessary and that's why I deleted it. When you said that you wanted seriously to learn, etc. I also intended to up-vote the question but it was locked. Anyway... you seem to be a nice guy and don't understand why certain things happen and that's why I said all this. I hope that you will not take this badly, just that I am a person who likes saying things openly (to help, contribute to improve things and stuff). I hope that I will see you in the future, answering questions with a proper name :)

Comment: You didn't steal anything. It is just that I don't understand certain attitudes too well: just the code (without understanding how it works) does not have any real value; and the best way to learn is doing things by your own. I do apologise for having said things a bit roughly. I am not too good at getting in touch in general (although it might seem otherwise, I am a pretty anti-social guy, LOL); if you need anything, you can get my email from my profile.